# Is it possible to use a nginx proxy on the same port as the listening port?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, proxy

I have a server on the localhost port 8080.

```
python3 -m http.server 8080 --bind localhost
```

I'd like to serve this using a reverse proxy using nginx.

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    location / { proxy_pass http://localhost:$server_port; }
}
```

So when accessing my-website.com:8080, the nginx should forward it to localhost:8080.

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

But I get an error that the address is already in use.

```
Jan 24 19:21:15 ip-172-31-46-125 nginx[23837]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Jan 24 19:21:15 ip-172-31-46-125 nginx[23837]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

On Mac OS I don't get the error but on an Ubuntu instance, it does.

Comment: You should be getting the error on all operating systems - a port number is an operating system level global resource.  You'll need to chose a different port for each process.

Comment: Ya that's what I'll do. I'm not sure why it was working on my macos.